# NOT NULL constraint failed: Trying to save formset

Tags: python, django, formset

Note: Django/Python beginner, hope this question is clear.

I'm creating a form where multiple instances of a model (Guest) can be edited at once in a single form, and be submitted at the same time.

This Guest model is linked to a parent model, Invite, meaning multiple Guests are attached to a single Invite.

I've managed to create a formset for each Guest and display it, but when I submit it, I get the following error.

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: app_guest.invite_id
```

I *assume* this is because it doesn't have an invite to save the data to, but I can't figure out where to put this `invite_id` it's asking for.

Here's my view so far:

```
def extra_view(request, code):
    # Get the specific invite
    invite = get_invite(code)

    # Get guests attached to this invite
    guests = invite.guest_set.all()

    # Get the context from the request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # Store object of guests marked as attending
    guests_attending = invite.guest_set.filter(attending=True, invite=invite)

    form = ExtraForm(data=request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        # Save the new category to the database.
        ### FAILS HERE
        form.save(commit=True)

        # Go to Confirm page
        HttpResponseRedirect('confirm')
    else:
        # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal for now
        print form.errors

    if guests_attending.count() > 1:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        guest_formset = modelformset_factory(Guest, form=ExtraForm, extra=0, max_num=guests_attending.count())

        # Filter the formset so that only guests marked as attending are
        filtered_guest_form = guest_formset(queryset=guests.filter(attending=True))

        # Return the view
        return render_to_response('weddingapp/extra.html', {'GuestForm': filtered_guest_form, 'invite': invite, 'guests_attending': guests_attending, 'form_errors': form.errors}, context)

    else:
        # Since there's no guests to create a form for, return Confirm view
        return render(request, 'weddingapp/confirm.html', {
            'invite': invite,
        })
```

Here's my Guest model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Guest(models.Model):
    invite = models.ForeignKey(Invite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    diet = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    transport = models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    attending = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.guest_name
```

And here's the form:

```
class ExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    diet = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter your diet restrictions", required=False)
    transport = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, help_text="Will you be needing transport?", required=False)

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Guest
        fields = ('diet', 'transport')
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Even advice about a better way to structure all this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't include the `invite` field, so you have to set it before saving to the database.

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Save the new category to the database.
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.invite = invite
    instance.save()  # save to the db, now that we have set the invite
    ...
```